# xmlhttprequest.open() should not reload page or direct to requested URL

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am developing a website and trying to make it as interactive as possible, so the least page reloads or redirections possible.

I need to submit a form through the `POST`method:

```
<form method = "post" id = "form"> 
        #<Text Inputs>
        <input type = "submit" class = "form-control" onclick = "post_to_url('/url/', $('#form').serialize()); ">
</form>
```

And I am using this code to submit it using `XMLHttpRequest`

```
function post_to_url(url, content){
    const xhr = createXmlHttpRequestObject();

    xhr.onload = function () {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
    };

    xhr.open('POST', url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", url + "x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
    xhr.send(content); 
}

function createXmlHttpRequestObject(){
    var xmlHttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else{
        xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    return xmlHttp;
}
```

My problem is that even using this code the page still reloads. In the backend, if my application (using `Python Flask`) redirects to the page I have requested from, the page just reloads. If the application returns a response text, the browser gets directed to the url I am posting to and displays the response text in a page for itself.

I have looked at a [w3schools Try It example](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_post2) that makes a post request in the same way as I do. Here, the request is clearly done in the background without affecting the interface seen by the client that browses the website.

So I would like to know: Have I missed something? Are there different procedures for the XMLHttpRequest depending on how the server responds? Any answers are welcome and will be attentively considered.

Comment: Try returning `false` in your `post_to_url`

Comment: @Keith — That won't help. The `onclick` function ignores the return value of `post_to_url`

Comment: @Quentin  Yes, sorry, should have also mentioned.. `return post_to_url`,..  But anyway, addEventListener is a better option..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page reloading has virtually nothing to do with your JavaScript.

You are clicking a **submit button** that is inside a form!

---

Modern JavaScript would bind the event handler to the form's submit event using JS (instead of the submit buttons click event using HTML).

You can then prevent the default behaviour of a form submission.

```
const form = document.querySelector("form");
form.addEventListener("submit", form_handler);
function form_handler(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Don't submit the form normally
    post_to_url('/url/', $(this).serialize()); 
}
```

---

Do write server-side code to handle a regular form submission [when the JS fails](https://kryogenix.org/code/browser/everyonehasjs.html). This is [best practice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

Comment: Yes it works! Wow, thanks so much, I should've seen it. Thank you for your effort.